# Getting problem when uploading the data in server in iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c

I am getting a problem when I am uploading the data to server.
Actually my code seems like this:

```
-(void)publishToServer:(AddDetailsObject *)aCustObj
{

 NSString *urlString = @"http://219.91.165.17:8080/uploadIphone/upload.jsp";
 UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithData:custObj.picture];
 NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(theImage,0.9);

 //NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
 //NSString *uniquePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@".caf"];
 printf("\n recordedTmpFile......%s",[recordedTmpFile UTF8String]);
 NSData *audioData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[recordedTmpFile dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
 printf("\n length of data...%d",[data length]);

 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
 [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

 NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
 NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
 [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

 NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
 if([custObj.userName length]>0)
 {
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:custObj.userName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 }
 if([custObj.phoneNumber length]>0)
 {
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"phoneNo\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:custObj.phoneNumber] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

 }
 if([custObj.audioDuration length]>0)
 {
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"duration\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:custObj.audioDuration] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 }
 if([custObj.imeiNumber length]>0)
 {
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"imei\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:custObj.imeiNumber] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 }
 if([custObj.latitude length]>0)
{
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"latitude\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:custObj.latitude] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 }
 if([custObj.longitude length]>0)
 {
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"longitude\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:custObj.longitude] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 }
 if([custObj.messageTitle length]>0)
 {
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:custObj.messageTitle] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 }
if([custObj.picture length]>0) //Here Im getting the problem in server returndata I am getting only image but the audio file is not getting if the audio file code is above this picture code then audio file is returned but picture is not returned.
 {
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picture\"; filename=\"test.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [postBody appendData:imageData];
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 }
 if([audioData length]>0)
 {
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"audio.caf\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [postBody appendData:audioData];
  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 }
  [request setHTTPBody:postBody];
 NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
 NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 printf("\n return string:%s",[returnString UTF8String]);

}
```

Is there any limit for uploading data to server?

Please guys get me out of this problem.

Hope I will get a quick response from your side.
Thanks in advance,
Monish.

Comment: What problem you are getting? have you checked the console? What does it say.

Comment: Actually here the control is going only into both picture and data conditions but in server only image is uploading but the audiofile is not uploading.

Comment: Can anyone please suggest me is there anything wrong in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you haven't encoded the file content properly. 
According to the [RFC2388](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt) you need to encode the content of the files before writing it to the request. As the whole request uses 7-bit character encoding so unless you send ascii text files you need to encode the content of the files somehow.

You can search the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt) section 6 for the correct encoding and fix your code, but I would recomend using an open source library that does that for you.

Here is how you send forms using ASIHttpRequest:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"Ben" forKey:@"first_name"];
[request setPostValue:@"Copsey" forKey:@"last_name"];
[request setFile:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/ben.jpg" forKey:@"photo"];
```

Check this one: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ I was using it succesfully for http. They claims support for multipart/form-data.